# How do i remove an object in my case

Tags: javascript

I am trying to remove an object based on the obj id.

I have something like

```
var array =[];
var id =3;

array [
   {
    id:'1',
    title:'test'
   },
   {
    id:'2',
    title:'tes2'
   },
   {
    id:'3',
    title:'tes3'
   }
]
```

How do I remove the object based on the id 3. thanks!

Comment: `array.splice(id-1,1);`

Comment: nominating for reopening - although `Array.prototype.filter` is still in use, finding an element vs. removing an element are different operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
array = array.filter( 
          function( item ) {
            return item.id != id;
          }
        );
```

Or, to modify the array in place:

```
for ( i = 0; i < array.length; ++i )
{
  if (array[i].id == id)
  {
    array.splice(i, 1);
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: That's not removing the array; that's returning a new array without that item. Although it works, it would be slower and consume way more memory than needed.

Comment: True. Added a modify-in-place version.

Comment: Coming in ES6: `var idx = array.findIndex(obj => obj.id === 3); if (idx !== -1) array.splice(idx, 1);`

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the previously-posted answer, if you, or your users, are using an up-to-date browser, then the following is available:

```
function removeByPropertyEquals(haystack, needleProp, needleVal) {
    haystack.forEach(function (obj, index) {
        if (obj[needleProp] === needleVal) {
            return index;
        }
    });
    return -1;
}

var id = 3,
    array = [{
        id: '1',
        title: 'test'
    }, {
        id: '2',
        title: 'tes2'
    }, {
        id: '3',
        title: 'tes3'
    }];

console.log( array );

array.splice(removeByPropertyEquals(array, 'id', '3'), 1);

console.log( array );
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/2FUz7/).

References:

- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`Array.prototype.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).